# Using both Checkboxes & Radio buttons with SelectOption in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am currently receiving an error at compile on being unable to find criteriaList() which returns the options from my SelectOption.  I was under the impression that radio buttons and checkboxes utilized the same technology but apparently not?

I have tried using the same syntax I used for the radio buttons, which do indeed work on their own.  But for some reason the checkboxes are presenting a problem.

My radio buttons on the VFP look like this

```
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!tenlan}" layout="PageDirection" >

        <apex:selectOptions value="{!consumerList}"/>

    </apex:selectRadio>
```

and so my checkboxes I did the same

```
    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!bbt}" layout="PageDirection">

        <apex:selectOptions value="{!criteriaList}"/>

        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
```

As for the controller.  I handled the Radio Buttons like this:

```
public List<SelectOption> getconsumerList(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Tenant', 'Tenant'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Landlord', 'Landlord'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Access', 'Access'));
    return options;
}
```

and of course I tried the same thing for my checkboxes.

```
public List<SelectOption> getcriteraList(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('bbt', 'Break Down By Trade'));
    return options;
}
```

After reading selectCheckBoxes here
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectCheckboxes.htm

it seemed that the boxes could indeed take strings instead of booleans as the options.add().  But I"m unsure why the compiler won't take criteriaList as an acceptable method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid this problem by instead just initiating two separate lists of selectOption.

```
public List<SelectOption>consumerList{get; set;}
public List<SelectOption>criteriaList{get; set;}
```

Then in the constructor I added my criteria to them.

```
 consumerList = new List<SelectOption>();
 criteriaList = new List<SelectOption>();
 consumerList.add(new SelectOption('Tenant', 'Tenant'));
 consumerList.add(new SelectOption('Landlord', 'Landlord'));
 consumerList.add(new SelectOption('Access', 'Access'));
 criteriaList.add(new SelectOption('bbt', 'BreakDownByTrade'));
```

I am a bit sad because I'm not quite sure why this was necessary but it did seem to fix the problem.